# all tag helpers works but asp-area doesn't

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

hi i am using this code but asp-area doesn't work.

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Sliders"  asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.SliderId" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

here is the result:
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44306/Sliders/Delete/3?area=Admin

all the routing with areas works fine and Sliders Controller has area attribute;

Comment: I have doubts that the problem might be the version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the orders of defining routes in `startup` class.
I believe now you have them like this (non-area route before area route):

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "defaultWithArea",
    pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Try to change their order (make area route before the non-area route).
And make sure to unset a default area from the area route, i.e:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "defaultWithArea",
        pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

otherwise, any link without area will be mapped to the default area used in defining the route in `startup`